# Paginate Eager Load Constraints

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am Using Laravel 4:

I am trying to paginate an Eager Loaded Constraint, essentially I have a Topics Model which has a *hasMany* relationship to a Comments Model. This is all well and good and no problems with that. However I would like to be able to display a paginated table of the Comments (of which there will be hundreds) on the admins edit topic view. To do this I thought I would use the following code:

```
$topic = Topics::with( array( 'comments' => function($query)
    {
        $query->orderby('created_at', 'DESC');
        $query->paginate(10);
    } ) )
->where('id', $id)
->first();
```

Now this will provide me `$topic` with the correct object and inspecting `$topic->comments` shows it has the correct linked comments and is limited to 10 results. The pagination also responds to the `GET` page parameter and will paginate, however trying to echo `$topic->comments->links()` results in an error of method not found.

My work around for this is to have a second query which counts the attached comments and then using the following in my view:

```
$paginator = Paginator::make($topic->comments->toarray(), $commentCount, 10);
echo $paginator->appends(array('tab' => 'comments'))->links();
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `paginate()` on your eager constraint it is configuring the query for you (setting the skip and take).  The paginator that is generated will actually be discarded.

Since you're just getting a single topic with its comments why not do this (same number of database calls)...

```php
$topic = Topic::find($id);
$comments = $topic->comments()->order_by('created_at DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Admittedly, you won't be able to use `$topic->comments` to get the paginator, and will have to use `$comments` instead, but that's not a terrible thing.

Comment: I suspected that was what was happening with the pagination. Thank you for your suggestion, as you say, it will work just as well - just not as pretty :)